# Looking for public news articles dataset with their associated categories

Tags: machine-learning, nlp

I'm looking for datasets that contain labeled news articles. I'm trying to build information retrieval application using latent semantic analysis.

I've already used:

1. [http://qwone.com/~jason/20Newsgroups/](http://qwone.com/%7Ejason/20Newsgroups/)
2. http://mlg.ucd.ie/datasets/bbc.html

These two are not big enough for my needs. I would like to have articles that are decent sized, liked articles on bbc, and there are a lot of them (more than 10k). What is more they must be categorized. I've found this: https://www.kaggle.com/snapcrack/all-the-news
but there is no info about categories. I can't find anything that would fulfill my needs.